# Bound Type Parameters in a Generic Method fail while an equivalent Generic Interface works, why?

Tags: java, eclipse, generics

Lets start with 3 interfaces.  What they do isn't important.  Just note that Car is parameterized (), while Foo and Bar are not.

```
interface Foo                               {void testFoo();}
interface Bar                               {void testBar();}
interface Car<A>                            {A    testCar();}
```

I want to 'composite' these interfaces, and this works just fine if I explicitly create the composites like this:

```
interface FooBar        extends Foo,Bar     {}
interface FooCar<A>     extends Foo,Car<A>  {}
```

However, I'd much prefer to implicitly composite the interfaces via the bounded type declarations of various methods.  For example:

```
public <T extends Foo & Bar>        T   implicitFooBar()    {return null;}
public <X, T extends Foo & Car<X>>  T   implicitFooCar()    {return null;}
```

**WORKs:** The **implictFooBar()** method returns a type T which implements both the Foo and Bar interfaces (a composite if you will).  A call to this method compiles, and I can avoid having to explicitly declare the FooBar interface:

```
// implicit composition of Foo and Bar, GOOD
FooBar implicitFooBar = implicitFooBar();
implicitFooBar.testFoo();
implicitFooBar.testBar();
```

**FAILs:** However, a call to **implicitFooCar()** fails to compile.  The error message is "The method implicitFooCar() in the type GenericsTest is not applicable for the arguments ()"  (*I wrapped my test code in a class called GenericsTest.*)

```
// implicit composition of Foo and Car<X>, FAIL!
//Compiler says "The method implicitFooCar() in the type GenericsTest is not applicable for the arguments ()"
FooCar<Number> implicitFooCar = implicitFooCar();   //compile error on method call
implicitFooCar.testFoo();                           
Number n2 = implicitFooCar.testCar();
```

The compiler error only shows when the type declaration is both compound and parameterized.  For example, both of these compile and can be called just fine:

```
public <X>                      Car<X>  justCar()       {return null;}
public <X, T extends Car<X>>    T       implicitCar()   {return null;}
```

## Question...

I suspect this has something to do with type erasure, but I'd like to understand the details of what's going on here.  I've read the Oracle Generics Tutorials, but I'm not seeing what combination of rules the implicitFooCar() method violates, while implicitFooBar() and implicitCar() are fine.  I'm looking for an academic style explanation, not just a work around.

## Bonus

Interestingly enough, the following variant of calling the implicitFooCar() method works (no compiler errors.)  This hints at why the other version doesn't work, but I've yet to connect those dots.

```
//variant... GOOD... but why?
implicitFooCar = this.<Number,FooCar<Number>>implicitFooCar();
```

## Test Code (whole)

If you want to play with the code, here it is as a single class.

```
public class GenericsTest {

    public static interface Foo                             {void testFoo();}
    public static interface Bar                             {void testBar();}
    public static interface Car<A>                          {A testCar();}

    public static interface FooBar      extends Foo,Bar     {}
    public static interface FooCar<A>   extends Foo,Car<A>  {}



    public <X>                          Car<X>      justCar()           {return null;}

    public                              FooBar      explicitFooBar()    {return null;}
    public <T extends Foo & Bar>        T           implicitFooBar()    {return null;}

    public <X>                          FooCar<X>   explicitFooCar()    {return null;}
    public <X, T extends Foo & Car<X>>  T           implicitFooCar()    {return null;}

    public <X, T extends Car<X>>        T           implicitCar()       {return null;}


    public void test() {
        justCar().testCar();

        // explicit composition of Foo and Bar, GOOD
        FooBar explicitFooBar = explicitFooBar();
        explicitFooBar.testFoo();
        explicitFooBar.testBar();

        // explicit composition of Foo and Car<X>, GOOD
        FooCar<Number> explicitFooCar = explicitFooCar();
        explicitFooCar.testFoo();
        Number n1 = explicitFooCar.testCar();

        // implicit composition of Foo and Bar, GOOD
        FooBar implicitFooBar = implicitFooBar();
        implicitFooBar.testFoo();
        implicitFooBar.testBar();

        // implicit composition of Foo and Car<X>, FAIL!
        //Compiler says "The method implicitFooCar() in the type GenericsTest is not applicable for the arguments ()"
        FooCar<Number> implicitFooCar = implicitFooCar();   //compile error on method call
        implicitFooCar.testFoo();                           
        Number n2 = implicitFooCar.testCar();
        //variant... GOOD... but why?
        implicitFooCar = this.<Number,FooCar<Number>>implicitFooCar();

        // implicit (no composition) Car<X>, GOOD
        Car<Number> implicitCar = implicitCar();
        Number n3 = implicitCar.testCar();

    }

}
```

## UPDATE

This compiles with javac version 1.8.0_60 (and _45 per comments), but Eclipse's (version 4.4.2.M20150204-1700) built in compiler ECJ is reporting the error mentioned above.
*I added an eclipse tag to this question, as this may be an EJC issue.*

Comment: Your code sample at the bottom compiles for me (Java 1.8.0_45).  What is your Java version?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do, but it's not going to work.  In particular, the signature you have written for `implicitFooBar` claims that for any type that implements `Foo` and `Bar`, it can return that type.  This will only work if you return `null`; it won't work if you try to return an actual object.  Java's type system can't express what you're trying to do.

Comment: @LouisWasserman For background... I'm working on a fluent API.  The explicit interfaces list available actions at points in the API syntax, and the implicit interfaces are required where multiple sets of actions are possible in the syntax.
Good point about the implementation currently returning null.  I haven't started coding the implementation (just translating the API spec so far) and I'll probably end up needing those intermediate interfaces at that point in time.

Comment: There's not, I'm afraid, really a better way than either a) having interfaces for all the different subsets of actions that might be available, or b) giving up on expressing this in the type system.

Comment: @rgettman Java 1.8.0_60  (The compiler error is showing up in Eclipse.  I verified that the project has the 1.8.0_60 library, and is set to compile src to 1.8)

Comment: @LouisWasserman I concede I'll have issues when I attempt to implement the method body.  Set that issue to the side though and help me understand why the compiler would permit a call to implicitFooBar() and implicitCar(), and not implicitFooCar().

Comment: @rgettman  hmm, somethings fishy here. This compiles on the command line for me too (verified via javac -version that it's 1.8.0_60)

I tweaked the test class (added a main that runs test, and implemented the interface methods) and was able to run this without issue.

So... it looks like Eclipse's compiler (ECJ) may be too aggressive in marking that method call as an error.  I'll need to test some more to ensure that Javac is able to infer the result type correctly though.

Comment: Turns out this is just an issue with Eclipse's built in compiler, ECJ.  In Luna (v4.4) ECJ indicates an error on the specified line.  I installed and tested Eclipse Mars.1 Release (4.5.1) Build id: 20150924-1200 and the same code now compiles cleanly in eclipse (as id did with javac 1.8.0_60).  I do not have a reference to an ECJ bug report, but I thing the test is proof enough.  @rgettman if you'll post an answer, I'll mark it correct.  (meta question:  should I edit/rewrite the question to be more ECJ focused?  As is, the question and answer seem very orthogonal.)

Comment: You've included Eclipse and its version in your question now; that should be sufficient.  Also, you can answer your own question; that is encouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to directly answer my question...  It IS possible to declare a method with a bound parameterized type that combines two interfaces, one of which is parameterized itself.

The *implicitFooCar()* method from my example failed because of a bug in the Eclipse compiler ECJ used in Luna, version 4.4 of Eclipse.  The same code compiled using the javac compiler (v 1.8.0_60) and in the next version of Eclipse, Mars (4.5).

Second, my desire to avoid explicit declarations of what I thought of as temporary or intermediary composite interfaces, was short sighted.  Louis Wasserman [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33683605/bound-type-parameters-in-a-generic-method-fail-while-an-equivalent-generic-inter?noredirect=1#comment55140315_33683605) that the method will at some point need to return an object that conforms to that composite specification, and thus I'll need an explicit version at that point.